# .addClass from JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, addclass

I got this piece of code which is working perfectly fine:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {
        $("tbody button").addClass( "btn-lg" );
        $("tbody button").removeClass( "btn-sm" );
    } else if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $("tbody button").removeClass( "btn-lg" );
        $("tbody button").addClass( "btn-sm" );
    } else {
        $("tbody button").removeClass( "btn-lg" );
        $("tbody button").removeClass( "btn-sm" );
    }
});
```

But that doesn't work when I open the document since I'm not doing any resize, so I added this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1024) 
        $("tbody button").addClass( "btn-lg" );
    else if ($(window).width() <= 768)
        $("tbody button").addClass( "btn-sm" );
});
```

But somehow it's not working, I inserted a console.log to see if the code was reaching inside the *if* and indeed it was, but somehow it's not adding the class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: relevant html please?

Comment: Maybe you are creating the buttons inside the table in a javascript `for` somewhere and they do not exist when the code runs for the first time? Try to print out `$("tbody button").length` to see what's being set.

Comment: indeed friend, thanks

Comment: You may need to do an ".each" on the $("tbody button") to add the class.

Comment: Tried adding a `.trigger('resize');` onto your resize statement?

Comment: Luan Nico told me the problem, the buttons weren't created initially on the html code since I had to wait for an API request first to give me the data to display.

Comment: Use [window load event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668611/jquery-width-incorrect-immediately-after-document-ready).

Answer (score 1):

One possible alternative would be to wrap the buttons in `visible-lg` divs instead of using javascript. Example:

```
<div class="visible-lg">
    <button class="btn btn-lg"></button>
</div>
<div class="visible-md">
    <button class="btn"></button>
</div>
<div class="visible-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-sm"></button>
</div>
```