# Understanding Jquery function - $(document).ready(callback);

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

Hi am trying to run a function on window resize and document ready. As resize is triggered by mobile scroll it is necessary to check the height hasn't changed. This code works for resize but not on load. Is anyone able to explain whey the function isn't executed on document ready? Thanks in advance.

```
    //CLOSE EXPANDED ELEMENTS FOR MOBILE

var $window = $(window);
var width = $(window).width();


var callback = function () {



        if($(window).width() != width){

            if ($window.width() < 756) {
            $(".content_lower.collapse").removeClass('in');
          }
            else {
              $(".content_lower.collapse").addClass('in');
            }

        }

};

$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);
console.log(callback.toString());
```

Comment: Actually it's called but on load `width = $(window).width()` so the function will enter the condition and nothing will be done with the function.

Comment: Yeah I see, I was suspecting something like that. Cheers

Comment: Instead of `$(document).ready()`, you may want to use `.load()` which waits for all content including images to be loaded. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668644/1381809).

Comment: @Robaggs please see myb EDITED answer, you will find the explanation and the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually on document ready the document is just loaded and the `$(window).width()` is equal to `width` variable.

So the function `callback` will be called while `width = $(window).width()` so it will not enter the if condition and nothing will happen inside the function.

If you try to log somtheing to the console or alert a message in the beginning of your function you will see that it's executed:

```
var callback = function() {
  console.log("Callback entered !!!");

  if ($(window).width() != width) {
    if ($window.width() < 756) {
      $(".content_lower.collapse").removeClass('in');
    } else {
      $(".content_lower.collapse").addClass('in');
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT:**

If you still want to execute it in document load you can add a boolean flag initialized to `false` and set it to `true` if the window is once resized then test with it:

```js
var $window = $(window);
var width = $(window).width();
var called = false;

var callback = function() {
  console.log("callback entered !!!");
  if ($(window).width() != width || !called) {

    if ($window.width() < 756) {
      $(".content_lower.collapse").removeClass('in');
    } else {
      $(".content_lower.collapse").addClass('in');
    }

  }
  called = true;
};

$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);
console.log(callback.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content_lower.collapse">the div</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**

A better approach is to use the boolean flag as a parameter of the `callback` function, and call it with `false` on document load and `true` on window resize:

```
    var $window = $(window);
    var width = $(window).width();

    var callback = function(resized) {

      if ($(window).width() != width || !resized) {
        if ($window.width() < 756) {
          $(".content_lower.collapse").removeClass('in');
        } else {
          $(".content_lower.collapse").addClass('in');
        }
      }
    };

    $(document).ready(callback(false));
    $(window).resize(callback(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

This gave the desired effect. Tanks for the help guys.

```
var $window = $(window);
var width = $(window).width();


var callback = function () {
  if ($window.width() < 756) {
  $(".content_lower.collapse").removeClass('in');
  }
  else {
    $(".content_lower.collapse").addClass('in');
  }
};

$(document).ready(callback);
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() != width){
    callback();
  }
});
```

Comment: If any one can shorten this I'd be interested in how thats done :)

Comment: Nice approach too, take a look at my answer I included a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

When the document is loaded the `width` variable will be set to your window-width (let's say 500px). Then it checks if the current window-width (so 500px) is equal to the `width` var (`500 !== 500`). This returns `false`, so you code won't be executed. You can do this instead:

```js
var callback = function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 756) {
    $('body').text($(window).width() + " - if");
  } else {
    $('body').text($(window).width() + " - else");
  }
};

$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tidy, problem is then resize is called on scroll for mobile device. Which means the div collapses as you scroll. f ($(window).width() != width) { this is preventing that from happening. Trying to figure out how to integrate it.