# Wrong dimensions retrieved from div on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Robotto Monospace font and i need to calculate its single characters width.So i am doing it like this

```js
var singleCharacterWidth;

function calculateCharactersWidth() {
  var x = $('<div>').text('A').appendTo('#hiddenView');
  singleCharacterWidth = x.width();
  $('#hiddenView').empty();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  calculateCharactersWidth();
  
  console.log(singleCharacterWidth);
});
```

```css
#hiddenView {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'RobotoMono-Regular';
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="hiddenView"></div>
```

When the page loads for the first time it gives wrong width and after reloading the page it gives proper width.

First time page loading `calculateCharactersWidth()` gives `9`. On reload it gives the proper character width i.e `7.20`

What's wrong with this?

**screenShot of console**

[image]

This doesn't happen when i use default monospace font.It always returns same width.  
So could it be related to loading of custom font..

Comment: I placed your code in a runnable snippet. Every time I run it I get `9`.

Comment: You calculate width, but you say height here "On reload it gives the proper character height i.e 7.28". Is it height or width you're after?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : screen shot attached please have a look t this..Actually i am loading this page on some click using .load() into parent page's div. does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this post : 
[jQuery width() incorrect immediately after document ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668611/jquery-width-incorrect-immediately-after-document-ready)

The idea is to move your function call into a **$(window).load()** event instead of document ready !

It solved my issues many times, hope it'll help you

Comment: For me $(window).load() returns the same result as $(document).ready()

Comment: OK. This is weird because I don't really know how you got 7.28 tbh